# Difference between .tar.gz.asc, git.tar.bz2 and .tar.bz2

Tags: osx, software-installation, source

I have a Mac running OSX 10.9.1 and I want to install [Gerris](http://gfs.sourceforge.net/wiki/index.php/Mac_OSX_Installation) and its dependencies.

In the last lines of the page I have to install [ffmpeg](http://ffmpeg.org/releases/). But there are lots of releases of ffmpeg. Which one I should choose?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**.tar.gz.asc** - The files that end in `.asc` are ASCII files that contain a GPG key which you can use to confirm the authenticity of the other files within that directory. Only the author(s) of FFMpeg would be able to generate these keys using their private key to "sign" the other files there.

```
$ gpg --verify ffmpeg-0.10.10.tar.bz2.asc
gpg: Signature made Tue 05 Nov 2013 08:44:09 PM EST using RSA key ID D67658D8
gpg: Can't check signature: public key not found
```

Note the key ID above, `D67658D8`. That's a hexidecimal string so it's typically written later on like this: `0xD67658D8`

Use this command to import `ffmpeg`'s GPG key from a key server:

```
$ gpg --keyserver x-hkp://pool.sks-keyservers.net --recv-keys 0xD67658D8
gpg: requesting key D67658D8 from hkp server pool.sks-keyservers.net
gpg: key D67658D8: public key "FFmpeg release signing key <ffmpeg-devel@ffmpeg.org>" imported
gpg: no ultimately trusted keys found
gpg: Total number processed: 1
gpg:               imported: 1  (RSA: 1)
```

Now verify the package:

```
$ gpg --verify ffmpeg-0.10.10.tar.bz2.asc
gpg: Signature made Tue 05 Nov 2013 08:44:09 PM EST using RSA key ID D67658D8
gpg: Good signature from "FFmpeg release signing key <ffmpeg-devel@ffmpeg.org>"
gpg: WARNING: This key is not certified with a trusted signature!
gpg:          There is no indication that the signature belongs to the owner.
Primary key fingerprint: FCF9 86EA 15E6 E293 A564  4F10 B432 2F04 D676 58D8
```

**.git.tar.bz2** - these are often a snapshot build from the the project source code repository, where the developers commit FFMpeg as they work on it. Often times these are automatically built, and so they may not be guaranteed to work.

**.tar.bz2** - these are the actual sources for the various versions of FFMpeg. If you're attempting to build a software package from source, these are likely the ones you want.

If you don't need to install from source (which can be a complex task the first couple of times), you might want to check if you can use [MacPorts] versions of these tools, if they exist, instead.

Comment: I have brew instead of MacPorts and the page says install from source somewhere. Does source mean the directory in which ffmpeg is installed?

Comment: @user3115779 - no from source means to download the files (.tar.bz2) and compile them. Can you pastebin the actual output and post a link here? I don't have OSX, but have use macports to help friends out in the past.

Comment: how can I paste bin?

Comment: http://pastebin.com is the website, you copy paste the output to that site, it will give you a unique URL for the content.